# How to count LanguageServer completion requests that have occurred from within a VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We have a request to count the number of 'completion' events that have occurred from our LanguageServer in the vscode-python extension. (After a number of these completion events, we want to raise a popup and ask the user for some feedback).

I've not found a way to do this without asking for a change from the LanguageServer itself (have it raise an event that I can hook into). I am wondering if there is such a facility already available though, within VSCode?

I have found the BaseLanguageClient.onNotification from within the vscode-languageclient library. I am not entirely sure what method to hook into with this though, or even if there is an event relevant to my need.

Anyone have any tips for this?

Comment: Also asked here, I will be sure to update both as information arrives... https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54404

Answer (score 0):

You can inject middleware into your LanguageClient in order to capture events such as these. See here for an example:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/blob/e0f8fc2540fecfe964807b97b1e4276c6b6c7a21/src/goMain.ts#L113